# Can't load MYSQL Driver from site's subdirectory, can from main

Tags: php, mysql

First, I am completely a newbie when it comes to PHP.

A client bought a script, and **the installation script didn't work. I manually assembled a config file from how it's written in the installer.**

The front end works fine, loads the driver, connects to the database.

Visiting the admin, I get "`Error: Could not load database driver type mysql!`". The admin config file looks like this (the frontend's config is very similar)

```
// HTTP;
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://...');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://...');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://...');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://...');

// HTTPS;
## truncated for Stack's's sake, similar to above

// DIR;
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'system/database/');
## the above line is exactly the same as the frontend's config.php, as are most.
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'admin/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'catalog');

// DB;
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '...');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '...');
define('DB_DATABASE', '...');
define('DB_PREFIX', '...');
```

Most of the above lines are exactly the same as the frontend's configuration file, including, of course, database credentials.

But as soon as this code attempts to fire, I get the error

```
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
```

The credentials are correct, the exact same line is present in the frontend's config.

Both `index.php` and `admin/index.php` begin very similarly with the latter missing three requires that probably don't matter. I added them to the admin section and still get the same error.

I've tried changing the paths to begin with `/` and `../` and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `__DIR__` to get the current directory and then navigate to where it needs to be e.g. `define('DIR_DATABASE', __DIR__ .  '/system/database/');` or something like `define('DIR_DATABASE', __DIR__ .  '/../system/database/');`

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue but this is helpful to know. I'll keep trying. Thanks for this help.

Comment: Maybe the DB class needs to be imported properly? Are there any use statements at the top of the file?

Comment: There aren't, and I can verify that no files in in the application use `use` statements. (Notepad++ find for `\buse\b` [regular for "use" as a whole word] returns nothing, other than plain text in the license.)

Comment: `echo(file_exists( __DIR__ . '/../system/database'))` is returning `1`, where `echo(file_exists('system/database'));` and `'../sytem/database'` were not. So I'm seemingly a step closer. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any definitions (define) in the system/database file? If there are you may have to do the same __DIR__ trick in there.

Comment: No there aren't. I don't know if this is unusual for but I can't create an error by creating bad syntax in `/database/system/mysql.php` or even by renaming the whole folder. The installation routine also only calls three functions, `setup_mysql($options); write_config_files($options); dir_permissions();` which each do as the names imply, directory copying or anything.

Comment: Is DIR_DATABASE in the codebase outside of the DEFINE as above?

Comment: It is in DB class' __construct as follows `$file = DIR_DATABASE . $driver . '.php';   if (file_exists($file)) {...` printing $file in the error's exit is giving me exactly this: `DIR_DATABASEmysql.php`. I'm baffled.

Comment: It looks as though the define('DIR_DATABASE') is not being included in the DB class? which is why it's saying DIR_DATABASE and not ../system/database

Comment: Hmm. Index.php in `/` and `/admin/` both `require_once('config.php');` well before `new DB(...)` is called. I can't thank you enough for the effort you've put forth.

Comment: Shouldn't require_once('config.php') be more like `require_once(__DIR__ . '/config.php');`? And no worries - we've all had issues before with code.

Comment: So, during my edits, `DATBASE` happened somehow, but that wasn't the initial problem. I have an admin section now visible and `__DIR__` seems necessary. **Thanks for all your effort!** (I hate PHP, lol)

Comment: No worries. Relative paths aren’t that great in php!

Answer (score 0):

This error presents because you don't have the package `php-mysql` installed.
If you use Ubuntu, for example, you can install the package doing

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

in the terminal.
Then, confirm that you want to continue with the installation.

Now you should have mysql for php working fine. Better to restart your webserver if needed.

For apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php-fpm restart
```

If you have php7.*, use

```
sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Edit the "0" per your needs (if you have 7.1, 7.2, etc).

Comment: The frontend works and connects to the database properly. I _don't think_ this is my issue.